Is hayagriva considered a major Vishnu incarnation?
he is famous for restoring the Vedas to Brahma and is considered a patron deity for education by Srivaishnavites who have built many temples to him.
Which of his great deeds are related in scriptures earlier than the itihasapuranas such as Vedas, Brahmanas etc.?

Mahabharata says that Hayagriva slew the Daityas Madhu and Kaitabha

After this, Hari, granting unto the Grandsire intelligence of the
foremost order relating to the Creation, disappeared there and then
for going to the place he had come from. It was thus that Narayana,
having assumed the form equipt with the horse-head, slew the two
Danavas Madhu and Kaitabha (and disappeared from the sight of
Brahma). Once more, however, he assumed the same form for the sake of
causing the religion of Pravritti to flow in the universe.'


SECTION CCCXLVIII, Moksha Dharma Parva, Mahabharata.

